# R Error: Format=NA

Tags: r, time, min

I'm trying to allocate my time data into 15 minutes of discrete interval. However, it shows error in Minimum Value. Anyone has any idea of this?

THis is my data

```
"10-28-15","00:04:13","13-01","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:16","13-10","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:30","13-11","1"
"10-28-15","11:59:44","13-12","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:48","13-13","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:50","13-14","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:57","13-15","0"
"10-28-15","00:37:57","13-17","0"
"10-28-15","00:45:04","13-17","0"
"10-28-15","00:13:04","13-17","0"
```

This is my R Script:

```
sample<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\Parkeasy\\Sunway\\parkeasy.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
sample$int<- strptime(paste(sample$V1,sample$V2),format="%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
min_V2<-trunc(min(strptime("2015-10-28 00:00:01", "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"),"min")
max_V2<-trunc(min(strptime("2015-10-28 23:59:59", "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")),"min") + 900
out <- cut(sample$int, breaks = seq(min_V2, max_V2, by = "15 min"))
```

Shows error when i execute the `min_V2`

```
min_V2
POSIXlt[1:1] Format:NA
```

and

> Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Answer (score 2):

Your date formats are mismatched.

```
min_V2<-trunc(min(strptime("2015-10-28 00:00:01", "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"),"min")
max_V2<-trunc(min(strptime("2015-10-28 23:59:59", "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")),"min") + 900
```

Instead of `%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S`, you want `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` to match your date string.